# JMeter Reporting Dashboard for Web Applications

Tags: jmeter

I am currently using JMeter and creating a report using the Report Dashboard for a web application but I noticed that the values are being displayed by specific request and not by transaction. I would like to ask if there is a way to combine these results into just one line item. See attached for sample screenshot. Instead of displaying individually, I would like to display it by transaction. So in this case it should be only **App_Launch** and not **39 App_Launch**, **40 App_Launch** etc. etc. Thanks.

[Report Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxBUb.png)
[Script - App_Launch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkUmy.png)

Comment: Try using a [Transaction Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) and put the requests inside that. This will provide you the complete elapsed time for all the child requests inside it.

Comment: Hi Raj. Actually, the requests are already inside a Transaction Controller since they were recorded. I have attached a small snapshot of the script. Even though the individual requests were already inside a Transaction Controller, I am still seeing individual requests in the Report Dashboard instead of one whole transaction. Do you have another idea on how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Try setting the property to **true** in **user.properties** `jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.show_controllers_only=true`.  This will display only the Transaction Controller results in dashboard.

For more information refer to [LINK](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)